# XSLT include empty elements in output

Tags: xml, xslt, sharepoint

I have a few simple xslt templates that I'm using to generate a navigation - the navigation is rendering fine but some of my markup is getting ignored.

The markup I need outputted is unrelated to the template itself but contains design elements I'd rather not inject with javascript.

My template:

```
<xsl:template match="Rows">
<nav id="nav">
    <a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="opener">
        <span class="ico">
            <sub />
            <sub /> 
            <sub />
        </span>
        <span>Menu</span>
    </a>    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Row[@FileDirRef = '/Lists/GlobalNavigation/GlobalNav']">
        <xsl:sort select="@DisplayOrder"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</nav>
</xsl:template>
```

But the empty `<sub>` elements render as nested elements:

```
<span class="ico">
  <sub>
    <sub>
      <sub>
      </sub>
    </sub>
  </sub>
```

Is there another way of doing this so empty elements will render out in the template?

Comment: Please add the XML input you use, and preferably a full XSLT stylesheet so that we can try and reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you seem to be generating html, if you have not told xslt to serialise as html it will serialise as xml as `<sub/>` which parses using an HTML parser as an open tag `<sub>` which would result in the tree you showed.

use

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
```

if you are generating no namespace element or

```
<xsl:output method="xhtml"/>
```

if you are using XSLT2 or 3 and generating XHTML namespace elements or use

```
<sub><xsl:text> </xsl:text></sub>
```

in the stylesheets so there is a space in the output so you get `<sub> </sub>` rather than `<sub/>`

Comment: That was it - I'm generating html with my template and this worked. Thanks, David!

`<sub><xsl:text> </xsl:text></sub>`

Comment: I had also tried `<sub></sub>` but adding the XSLT whitespace worked.

Comment: `<sub></sub>` and `<sub/>` is same after an XML parse so is same input to xslt so naturally makes same output. `<sub> </sub>` is different but xslt ignores white space normally so it still makes the same output.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. What exactly do you have to do in order to reproduce the original issue?

Comment: @michael.hor257k  xslt produced `<span><sub/><sub/><sub/></span>` but html doesn't recoginise `/>` and accepts unclosed elements so that parses using an html parser as `<span><sub><sub><sub></sub></sub></sub></span>`

Comment: Where/how can you observe this result of `<span><sub><sub><sub></sub></sub></sub></span>`?

Comment: @michael.hor257k any html parser eg put it in a browser and use the browsers DOM viewer to look at the structure, or in firefox at least just highlight it and view selection, but anyway that's the specified result as the parsing is specified in the html(5) spec.

Comment: Okay, I see it now. Though I am not sure what difference it makes (as these empty subs are not visible), at least the question is clear now, thank you.